# Order list alphabetically, distinct and uppercase

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to order a list alphabetically from A to Z, without doublon and in uppercase. The list is store in a variable like `@trigram`.

For example :

I have : Cap, yUM, HuI, aBc

And I want : ABC, CAP, HUI, YUM

With a `@trigram.each` I think but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with :

`@trigram = @trigram.order('trigramme asc').group("trigramme")`

Thank you all.

Comment: next time, you'd rather explain people you a db query to perform + your query doesnt handle case issues

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
ar = %w( Cap yUM HuI aBc cap )
ar.map(&:upcase).uniq.sort
#=> ["ABC", "CAP", "HUI", "YUM"]
```

Comment: I put :`<%- ar = %w(@trigram)%>
      <%- ar.map(&:upcase).uniq.sort %>` but that doesn't work